What is the equivalent fim of fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1?
I am trying to display an image on a display connected to my raspberrypi zero via ssh using:
sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 /path/to/some/file.png
I noticed that the newer version of fbi is called fim but I am unable to get it work.
What is the equivalent command in fim?
